# coffeescript: break for with if statement

Tags: for-loop, coffeescript, break

I'm trying to find the best way to accomplish a loop through an array, which should return a value once an "if" statement is matched.

I have two strings, and am trying to iterate through their characters and compare them (for a sort function). I need the iteration to break once the comparison condition is met.

Optimally, something like this:

```
a = 'here is one'
b = 'here is two'
if a.charCodeAt(i) < b.charCodeAt(i) then -1 else 1 for i in [0...a.length] when a.charCodeAt(i) != b.charCodeAt(i)
```

But, this translates to:

```
if (a.charCodeAt(i) < b.charCodeAt(i)) {
  return -1;
} else {
  _results = [];
  for (i = _i = 0, _ref = a.length; 0 <= _ref ? _i < _ref : _i > _ref; i = 0 <= _ref ? ++_i : --_i) {
    if (a.charCodeAt(i) !== b.charCodeAt(i)) {
      _results.push(1);
    }
  }
  return _results;
}
```

Another attempt:

```
pos = (if a.charCodeAt(i) < b.charCodeAt(i) then -1 else 1) for i in [0...a.length] when a.charCodeAt(i) != b.charCodeAt(i)
```

Translates to:

```
_results = [];
for (i = _i = 0, _ref = a.length; 0 <= _ref ? _i < _ref : _i > _ref; i = 0 <= _ref ? ++_i : --_i) {
  if (a.charCodeAt(i) !== b.charCodeAt(i)) {
    _results.push(pos = (a.charCodeAt(i) < b.charCodeAt(i) ? -1 : 1));
  }
}
return _results;
```

This is my current workaround:

```
a = 'here is one'
b = 'here is two'
return (for i in [0...a.length]
  do ->
    if a.charCodeAt(i) < b.charCodeAt(i) then -1 else 1
)[0]
```

Which translates to:

```
return ((function() {
  var _i, _ref, _results;
  _results = [];
  for (index = _i = 0, _ref = a['dep'].length; 0 <= _ref ? _i < _ref : _i > _ref; index = 0 <= _ref ? ++_i : --_i) {
    _results.push((function() {
      if (a['dep'].charCodeAt(index) < b['dep'].charCodeAt(index)) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    })());
  }
  return _results;
})())[0];
```

Does the job... but not ideal.
Ideas?

Comment: Uhm... `'foo'.localeCompare 'bar'`...!?

Answer (score 2):

Just use multiple lines, it makes it more readable anyway.

```
a = 'here is one'
b = 'here is two'
[x] = for i in [0...a.length] when a.charCodeAt(i) != b.charCodeAt(i)
    if a.charCodeAt(i) < b.charCodeAt(i) then -1 else 1
```